# c# selenium webdriver using firefox portable

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium

I want using selenium with portable firefox
and I need using two firefox with different profile in two location of hard disk but when create

FirefoxBinary
and  FirefoxProfile
and then FirefoxDriver  , browser alert =

Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible

please help me
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that selenium cannot find your selenium profile.  You have two options:

1. Let selenium create it's own profile.
2. Specify your own firefox profile.

For `#2`, you simply need to pass the argument:

```
-firefoxProfileTemplate /path/to/selenium.profile
```