# Setting the Firefox profile when using Selenium and Firefox Portable

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-grid, selenium-firefoxdriver, portable-applications

I'm in a setup, in which I need to use [Firefox Portable](http://portableapps.com/support/firefox_portable) 38.7.1 for my Selenium tests (version 2.53.0). Everything works fine, but now I need to configure a proxy.

I configured it in the default profile (it gets saved in `${FF_PORTABLE_PATH}/Data/profile/prefs.js`)

```
user_pref("network.proxy.http", "proxyHost");
user_pref("network.proxy.http_port", proxyPort);
user_pref("network.proxy.share_proxy_settings", true);
user_pref("network.proxy.ssl", "proxyHost");
user_pref("network.proxy.ssl_port", 51854);
user_pref("network.proxy.type", 1);
...
```

When starting the browser manually, this works fine. However, when triggered by Selenium an anonymous profile is created and used, which doesn't have my proxy settings.

I tried to specify the profile when starting the node.

At first I tried [using **-Dwebdriver.firefox.profile**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031253/what-profile-does-selenium-webdriver-use-by-default#20122365):

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role node -Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=default
```

Then I tried to use the default profile as a template [using **-firefoxProfileTemplate**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380813/c-sharp-selenium-webdriver-using-firefox-portable#22382334):

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role node -firefoxProfileTemplate "${FF_PORTABLE_PATH}/Data" -nodeConfig ...
```

I also created a new profile (using the [ProfilistPortable](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/profilistportable/) plugin) and specified it on startup of the node (with the `webdriver.firefox.profile`-parameter).

In all cases the Selenium node opens up Firefox Portable with a "clean" anonymous profile without my proxy settings.

Can anyone help me how to get this setup working with Firefox Portable? I don't really need separate profiles. As long as I can force Selenium to use a profile, which has the proxy configured, I'm fine.

Here's my nodeConfig:

```
{
    "capabilities": [
        {
            "browserName": "firefox",
            "version": "38.7.1",
            "firefox_binary": "${FF_PORTABLE_PATH}\\FirefoxPortable.exe",
            "platform": "WINDOWS",
            "maxInstances": 1,
            "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        }
    ],
    "configuration": {
        "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
        "maxSession": 1,
        "port": 5550,
        "host": "ip",
        "register": true,
        "registerCycle": 5000,
        "hubHost": "localhost",
        "hubPort": 4440
    }
}
```

I use ${FF_PORTABLE_PATH} in the examples above. In reality this (fully qualified) path is hardcoded in all my settings.

Comment: I am sad seeing no answer to this as I am also having trouble..

Comment: @martin - did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @CodeRocker unfortunately I haven't, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Digging into selenium code I was able to find a solution.

```
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File(portablePath.trim()));
File profile_dir = new File(portablePath.trim().replace("FirefoxPortable.exe", "/Data/profile"));
fp = new FirefoxProfile(profile_dir);
dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, fp);
driver  = new FirefoxDriver( binary , fp, dc);
```